# DecimalType issue while creating Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

While I am trying to create a dataframe using a decimal type it is throwing me the below error.

I am performing the following steps:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes._;


//created a DecimalType
val DecimalType = DataTypes.createDecimalType(15,10)
```

//Created a schema

```
val sch = StructType(StructField("COL1",StringType,true)::StructField("COL2",**DecimalType**,true)::Nil)

val src = sc.textFile("test_file.txt")
val row = src.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>Row.fromSeq(x))
val df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame(row,sch)
```

df1 is getting created without any errors.But, when I issue as df1.collect() action, it is giving me the below error:

```
scala.MatchError: 0 (of class java.lang.String)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$DecimalConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:326)
```

**test_file.txt content:**

```
test1,0
test2,0.67
test3,10.65
test4,-10.1234567890
```

Is there any issue with the way that I am creating DecimalType?

Comment: Read everything as StringType and cast to DecimalType later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should have an instance of `BigDecimal` to convert to `DecimalType`.

```
val DecimalType = DataTypes.createDecimalType(15, 10)
val sch = StructType(StructField("COL1", StringType, true) :: StructField("COL2", DecimalType, true) :: Nil)

val src = sc.textFile("test_file.txt")
val row = src.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x => Row(x(0), BigDecimal.decimal(x(1).toDouble)))

val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(row, sch)
df1.collect().foreach { println }
df1.printSchema()
```

The result looks like this:

```
[test1,0E-10]
[test2,0.6700000000]
[test3,10.6500000000]
[test4,-10.1234567890]
root
 |-- COL1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COL2: decimal(15,10) (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Looks like it is working. But, I am getting the below issue:   scala> val row2= src.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x=>Row(x(0),BigDecimal.decimal(x(1).toDouble)))
<console>:34: error: value decimal is not a member of object scala.math.BigDecimal
         val row2= src.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x=>Row(x(0),BigDecimal.decimal(x(1).toDouble))).           So I have tried like:      val row2= src.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x=>Row(x(0),BigDecimal(x(1).toDouble))) and I am able to get the result.     Any reason why the first value is showing as "0E-10" instead of 0.

Comment: 1.   BigDecimal() is equivalent to BigDecimal.decimal().

Comment: 2. showing as "0E-10" becase the type is decimal. `BigDecimal(0)` print `0`, but  `BigDecimal(0: Double)` should print `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file as `sc.textFile` it reads all the values as `string`, So error is due to applying the `schema` while creating `dataframe`

For this you can convert the second value to `Decimal` before applying `schema`

```
val row = src.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>Row(x(0), BigDecimal.decimal(x(1).toDouble)))
```

Or if you reading a cav file then you can use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to read csv file and provide the schema while reading the file.

```
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("cars.csv")
```

For Spark > 2.0

```
spark.read
      .option("header", true)
      .schema(sch)
      .csv(file)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: First method doesn't work, atleast not on Spark 1.6.

Comment: what ever you suggested is same as as cstur4 suggested. Both of you are correct. Please let me know if you know why 0 is showing as 0E-10 in the answer provided above.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to solve your problem would be to load the csv file directly as a dataframe. You can do that like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "false") // no header
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("/file/path/")
```

Or for Spark > `2.0`:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "false") // no headers
  .load("/file/path")
```

Output:

```
df.show()

+-----+--------------+
|  _c0|           _c1|
+-----+--------------+
|test1|             0|
|test2|          0.67|
|test3|         10.65|
|test4|-10.1234567890|
+-----+--------------+
```